# Access previous cell from layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell class. In that class I adjust the height of the cell depending on the image inside it.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    if (self.imageView.image) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,self.frame.origin.y,             
        self.frame.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
    }
}
```

But since they are all different heights some cells overlap each other.

[image]

The first image is the same height as the default cell height, therefore the second image is fine. The second image has a larger height which makes the third image to be positioned behind it.

Can I somehow access the previous cell from the layoutSubviews and adjust the y-position from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this in `layoutSubviews` instead of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, your code depends on a side effect and is trying to defeat `UITableView`. You should fix this in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and let the UITableView do the work for you.

Comment: How would I access the data I need from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: You would need a data model that lets you look up the correct image. Perhaps you have an NSArray called `images`. Then you would simply do something like this: `UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, and from there, determine the cell height that you need.

Comment: I have an array with the images in my custom TableViewController-class, how can I access that array in the custom cell class?

Comment: Accessing it from the TableViewController class is the right approach. That is where you should implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing a constant row height in the method

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 65; //For example
```

}

In the case, for example, that you have an array with the names of the images ordered (imageNamesArray), you can use something like this:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CGFloat desiredImageWidth = 50.0f;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    CGFloat ratio = image.size.height/image.size.width;

    return desiredImageWidth * ratio;
```

}